# TailwindCSS Building does not reflect config changes

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using Tailwind in a create-react-app and when I add a new color to the config file, it is not reflected when building, for example:

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extends: {
      color: {
        main: "#56435F",
      },
      textColor: {
        main: "#56435F",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

In styles folder I have two css files, one is `output.css` and the other is `tailwind.css` the `tailwind.css` contains:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And I am building with:

```
postcss -w src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/output.css
```

But whenever I add new things to the `tailwind.config.js` file, nothing gets rebuilt, no changes are actually reflected.

I feel like I am missing a piece of the puzzle, but I don't know what?